# Aligning in bootstrap with accordion

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am beginner in bootstrap. I am designing simple FAQ page with bootstrap like this.

[image]

This is my style. I try to change position, margin but I can't manage to shorten title and arrow to be middle. How shall I do?

```
<style>
 .faqHeader {
    font-size: 27px;
    margin: 20px;
}

.panel-heading [data-toggle="collapse"]:after {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\e072"; /* "play" icon */
    float: right;
    color: #F58723;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
    /* rotate "play" icon from > (right arrow) to down arrow */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);

}



.panel-heading [data-toggle="collapse"].collapsed:after {
    /* rotate "play" icon from > (right arrow) to ^ (up arrow) */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    color: #454444;

}
</style>


<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSeven">How did the Self Assessment Test come about?</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseSeven" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
                The Skill Optimiser Project Team has worked with all the Hiring Managers for the various job roles to understand the requirement based on 4 aspects: Product Knowledge, Job Expertise Knowledge/ Skills, Education/ Experience, and Competencies.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add following code to your styles:

```
.panel-heading [data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.panel-heading [data-toggle="collapse"]:after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 5px;
    float: right;  /*remove it*/
}
```

Using **position** instead of **float: right**. Remove your **float:right**.

According to your attached zip. I changed your styles in index.html as below. It worked.

```
.faqHeader {
    font-size: 27px;
    margin: 20px;
}
.panel-heading [data-toggle="collapse"] {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.panel-heading [data-toggle="collapse"]:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
...
```

[image]

Comment: I still cannot manage to do with that code. I have attached my simple html file here. Could you help to take a look? https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KwuucqmrMoc-XIkWgaaoc4C_ftOs5kwx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @KhantThuLinn I updated my answer according your attachment.

Comment: I am sorry. Can you help to send me your file? We are very close already. Just that on my side, I still cannot update with your code..not sure why..

Comment: @KhantThuLinn Can you give me your email so that I can send index.html file to you?

Comment: @KhantThuLinn I have sent the file to you, pls check it.